# Double checking exception and try-catch logic

Tags: java, exception, logic, try-catch

So just started this unit and answered a couple questions outta my book. Do my answers show proper understanding of exceptions and try-catch blocks? Wanted to verify this before i start working with try-catch blocks/exceptions :)

1. What classes (and their subclasses) are examples of unchecked exceptions?

   Answer: IOExceptions, ClassNotFoundException, RuntimeException (its subclasses: ArithmeticException, NullPointerException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, IllegalArgumentException
2. What are the two different ways that a programmer can deal with checked exceptions to avoid compil

   Answer: Use either a try-catch block or declare the exception in the method header beforehand.
3. Describe the steps that occur when an exception is not caught in the current method

   Answer: If an exception is not caught in the current method, Java exits this method, passes the exception to the method that invoke the method, and continues the same process to find a handler. If no handler found in the chain of methods being invoked, then the program terminates and prints an error message on the console. (ths process of finding the ‘handler’ is called catching and exception.
4. How is a ‘chained exception’ different from an exception that has been rethrown?

   Answer: A rethrown exception occurs when the handler cannot process the exception or simply wants to let its caller be notified of the exception. A chained exception is when you throw an exception along with another exception. Syntax for rethrowing exception: throw ex(ex = object reference) Syntax for chained exception: throw new Exception(“message…”, ex);

Comment: IOException and ClassNotFoungException are "checked" exceptions

Comment: 3. The program does not terminate; the *thread* where this happens usually does, and in practical applications this is very rarely the one and only thread left alive. Other threads keep going as usual. Also a thread may define an arbitrary *uncaught exception handler*, which can prevent the thread from dying.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hmm thats what it said in my book. Will double check it now!

Comment: Also, havent learned what threads are so i dont quite follow what ur saying marko.

Comment: Your statement is true only for the most trivial, "book-example" program, when there is only one thread around -- the *main* thread -- and that thread has the default uncaught exception handler.

Answer (score 1):

IOException and ClassNotFoundException are CHECKED exceptions. Only the RuntimeException and its derived classes are unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

1. IOException and ClassNotFoungException are "checked" exceptions. Take a look at the documentation to retrieve the whole list. (Checked Exceptions include "*Exception*" class and its sub-classes except for "RuntimeException" and its sub-classes which forms the "*Uncheck Exception*" group.  [Quick List](http://www.coderanch.com/t/540082/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/checked-unchecked-exception-list)
2. Try-catch block or a try-with-resources and propagate the exception to its caller. [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
3. The process is called propagation and if no handler is found, that the thread running will terminate (the message printed to the console is called the "*Stack Trace*"). The program itself would terminate only if the exception was propagated from the only one active remaining non-deamon thread (without finding any handler) [Thread types](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-difference-between-user-and-daemon-thread-in-java/196) | [Thread Concept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: The main thread is nothing special and in many real applications dies soon after program start.

Comment: Well, i believe that in single threaded scenario, where there is only one thread running, it will be running until the program ends. Another example might be that of Android applications, where there is a main/master thread (which menages the GUI and should not be used for time consuming processes), it will be on running state all the time to handle UI interactions.

Comment: The semantics of Java threads are clear: as long as there is any non-*daemon* thread running, the application runs. In the usual applications there are many non-daemon threads around. Your statement about the *main* thread designation is simply false.

Comment: I'm not putting down your comment,i agree with that, and i've mentioned the main thread just to make it clear that it doesn't always happen that the program terminates. Anyway i'm editing my answer